# Read file cookies.binarycookies (ios) and get uidnumber (ex: 100067613756726) with lua script on autotouch

Tags: lua, autotouch

[My file infomation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYd0h.png)

i try with code

local file = io.open("/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A77D3FC-6AD4-45CC-8373-C6805EE23053/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies", "r" )

local contents = file:read( "*all" )
alert( contents )

But it only show text "cook"
I want get uidnumber. tks all

This is content of file
cookï{á_8FMO¥GÄAè­'ÃA.facebook.comc_user/100067613756726f8FKMeáÅAè­'ÃA.facebook.comdatr/9dDmX1oeO8vxZf_c5oN3zo0G8FIKccÃAè­'ÃA.facebook.comfr/2nJPKLscDIQSFWe91.AWVLAExu1_bTrLxImZ6CSM8TzUQ.BgnyRL.bx.AAA.0.0.BgnyRL.AWWCQKMx204p8FIK¥GÄAè­'ÃA.facebook.comxs/46:Y_cRC0KmQk1Zbg:2:1621042254:-1:-1ß Kbplist00Ñ_NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy&(

Comment: A binary string might contain zero byte, which is treated as end-of-string by all standard text functions (such as alert)

Comment: `alert( (contents:gsub("%c", ".")) )`

Comment: But when I run your code, My Phone crashes and goes into Safe Mode. I have updated the content of the cookie file, can you reprocess it for me?

Comment: What is your Lua version?

Comment: `alert(contents:match"user/(%d+)")`

Comment: it not working. because 'local contents = file:read( "*all" )' cannot read file.

Comment: But you said: `But it only show text "cook"`  Which line of code prints text "cook"?

Comment: yes it is. but it only read "cook". it canot read all file. so alert(contents:match"user/(%d+)")  not working. it alert nil value

Comment: What is the output of `alert(#contents)` ?

Comment: alert(#contents) -> "cook"  no more. tks

Comment: `alert(#contents)` should display a number.  What is this number?

Comment: it is show "592"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari 5.1 cookie format specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545885/safari-5-1-cookie-format-specs)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get the UID, you can get it from this path: "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/"..fbPath.."/Documents/FBAPISessionLoggedInUserIDCache". The file contains just what you need.